# How to choose how far to move in primal dual path following algorithm?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

One of the Interior Point Methods is the Primal/Dual path following method.  In this method we decrease the log barrier term of the Barrier function, while still remaining primal and dual feasible.  At each iteration we need to solve the equations for the KKT conditions, including complementary slackness.  the complementary slackness means that the equations are non-linear, so we need to use newtons method to solve these equations.  Newton's method only gives you directions in which you can move to stay feasible, but then you have to decide how far to move in those directions. 
 So, essentially we need to know two things:

1)  The direction to move each of the variables.

2)  How *far* to move in each of those directions.

I'm confused on how far to move in those directions.

- I see one resource [here](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/ee236a/lectures/mpc.pdf) which seems to say on slide 10 that you can just move as far as possible that allows you to stay feasible.  Basically it says $\alpha_p = max(\alpha \ge 0 \vert s+\alpha\Delta s \ge 0)$ for the primal, and $\alpha_d = max(\alpha \ge 0 \vert z+\alpha\Delta z \ge 0)$ for the dual.
- I see another resource in the book Bertisimas and Tsitsiklis that suggests taking the minimum of these two values (on page 434):  $\beta_p = min(1, \alpha * min (\frac{x^k_i}{d^k_x}))$ and for the dual: $\beta_d = min(1, \alpha * min (\frac{s^k_i}{d^k_s}))$.  Apparently this will allow us to stay feasible, although it is not clear to me how.

How will these two approahces above allow us to stay feasible in the dual and primal sense?

Finally, Why can we not pick different different alpha values for the two dual variables, $d$ and $s$?  Both of these methods seem to agree that we must move the same amount for all of the dual variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question misquotes the formulas from page 10 of the lecture slides- you might want to correct this.

In practical implementations of the primal-dual interior point method, it's typical to find the largest step size that is less than or equal to one and that keeps the primal and dual iterates feasible with respect to the nonnegativity constraints.  In your notation, that means finding the largest $\alpha_{p}$ such as $x+\alpha_{p} \Delta x \geq 0$.

Both of your sources describe such a rule, although they use different notation.  You can max

$\max_{x+\alpha \Delta x \geq 0} \alpha  $

by using a ratio test and finding the minimum ratio of $x_{i}/(- \Delta x_{i})$ where the minimum is taken only over values of $\Delta x_{i}$ that are negative.

e.g. if $x_{1}=2$ and $\Delta x_{1}=-4$, then we must have $\alpha \leq 2/4=0.5$ to keep $x_{1}+\alpha \Delta x_{1} \geq 0$.

To answer your second question:  If you use a different step length for the two dual variables, then you can move from a point that is feasible with respect to the dual equality constraints to a point that is infeasible with respect to the dual equality constraints.  You want to retain feasibile with respect to these constraints.

Comment: "that keeps the primal and dual iterates feasible" we should say  _strictly_ feasible here, right? Or rather, they look for this maximum $\alpha_p$, $\alpha_d$ value, and back off a bit (e.g., the actual step taken is something like $0.999 \alpha_p$).

Comment: Yes - a typo, thank you @BrianBorchers.  I see that slide 10 is updating $s$ and $z$, but what about $x$?  It doesn’t seem to demand feasibility of $x$, it is only checking the primal variable $s$. And MichaelGrant that’s a minor detail but yes I think that’s true.

Comment: @MichaelGrant  Yes, but a relatively minor detail.  The main point here is that the ratio test is a way of finding the solution to the maximization problem given in the other source.

Comment: There's some confusion here caused by unusual notation.  In the lecture slides, the "dual" equations are $A^{T}z+c=0$, with the constraint $z \geq 0$, and the "primal" constraints are $Ax+s=b$, with $s \geq 0$.  The $x$ variable doesn't have a sign restriction.  This is explained at the start of the lecture.

Comment: In more conventional notation, the primal constraints are $Ax=b$, $x \geq 0$ and the dual constraints are $A^{T}y+z=c$, with $y$ free and $z \geq 0$.

Comment: @BrianBorchers, sorry - I'm still not quite grasping this.  I understand what is said in the lecture from Vandenberghe, but I do not understand the one with $\beta_p = min(1, \alpha * min (\frac{x^k_i}{d^k_x}))$ and for the dual: $\beta_d = min(1, \alpha * min (\frac{s^k_i}{d^k_s}))$.  Why is it necessary to have two $min$ scalar functions for each of these?  Thanks.

Comment: Also, to your answer to my second question - if we check feasibility for the two dual variables separately, and choose different distances to move for $s$ and $c$, then I think it would be feasible (no pun intended) to check feasibility for them separately, right?

Comment: The minimization with 1 and the minimum ratio ensures that if a full Newton's method step of length one is possible it will be taken (and we won't go further than one times $\Delta x$.)  The inner minmization ensures that no variable will go below 0.

Comment: The minimization with 1 and the minimum ratio ensures that if a full Newton's method step of length one is possible it will be taken (and we won't go further than one times $\Delta x$.)  The inner minmization ensures that no variable will go below 0.

Comment: Re/ the second question.  If $Ax+s=b$ and $A\Delta x + \Delta s=0$, then for any $\alpha_{p}$, $A(x+\alpha \Delta x)+ s + \alpha \Delta s=b$.  However, if two different values of $\alpha$ are used, then $A(x+\alpha_{1} \Delta x)+s+\alpha_{2} \Delta s \neq b$.  This is why the same value of $\alpha$ is used for both $x$ and $s$.

Comment: Note that in the maximization problem, the constraints are that both $\alpha \leq 1$ and $z+\alpha \Delta z \geq 0$ (meaning that each component of $z$ stays greater than or equal to 0.)

Comment: Great answers @BrianBorchers thankyou much!!!  When you say "and we won't go further than one times $\Delta x$" you are saying that if we still stay feasible while doing it, then we'll go all the way to the origin, like Newton's method usually does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62724/discussion-between-candic3-and-brian-borchers).